# Vue import css - Dynamic Url

Tags: css, vue.js, continuous-integration, cdn

We have been using Vue, shoe horned into a legacy MVC app for some time. The css classes have recently been moved to a CDN, which is controlled by another team.

In the components, we import the CSS like this:

```
<style scoped>
    @import "https://content.ourcdn.com/cdn-test/assets/css/search.min.css";
</style>
```

This all works fine, expect we need to change the URL when deploying to Production to the production CDN (Ie. `cdn` and not `cdn-test`).

Ideally the base Url would be held in a json file that could be replaced as part of our CI process.

Is any of this possible and am I looking at this from the right way?

Answer (score 0):

remove scoped, this must work..

```
<style>
    @import "https://content.ourcdn.com/cdn-test/assets/css/search.min.css";
</style>
```